# How shared state between separate component in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create Dropdown component.

When I click on the `DropdownHandler` component, I would like to save the state `isOpen` which can be `true` or `false`. If `true`, this same `state` is used by `<DropdownContent/>` to show the content. And by default, the `state` `isOpen` is `false` in `<Dropdown />` component

How can I do that please?

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {Dropdown, DropdownHandler, DropdownContent} from '../../components/Dropdown/Dropdown.jsx';

class HeaderConnected extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <Dropdown>
                 <DropdownHandler>
                     <Avatar title="Roberto"></Avatar>
                 </DropdownHandler>
                 <DropdownContent>
                     <li>Menu</li>
                     <li>Settings</li>
                 </DropdownContent>
               </Dropdown>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default HeaderConnected;
```

Dropdown.jsx

```
export class Dropdown extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            opened: false
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="DROPDOWN">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export class DropdownHandler extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="DROPDOWN__HANDLER">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export class DropdownContent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="DROPDOWN__CONTENT">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) for this.

Comment: Read [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) - they explain the idiomatic way of sharing state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution based on @Andrew answers. Not sure if this is right. But it solves the shared state, only use by Dropdown. I pass the handler and content via props

What do you think?

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {Dropdown} from '../../components/Dropdown/Dropdown.jsx';

class HeaderConnected extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <Dropdown handler={<Avatar title="Roberto" />}>
                  <li>Menu</li>
                  <li>Settings</li>
              </Dropdown>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default HeaderConnected;
```

Dropdown.jsx

```
export class Dropdown extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            opened: false
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="DROPDOWN">
               <div className="DROPDOWN_HANDLER" onClick="...">
                   {this.props.handler}
               </div>
               <div className="DROPDOWN_CONTENT">
                   {this.props.children}
               </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Always declare props in component. And you can remove your constructor and declare your state directly in the component (look at my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use redux.
You set and control your opend like state of child component and set it to DropdownContent with props. So when you will change opend by click on DropdownHandler, your DropdownContent will recive new propse and call re-render.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Dropdown, DropdownHandler, DropdownContent} from '../../components/Dropdown/Dropdown.jsx';

class HeaderConnected extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            opened: false
        }
    }
    onClick(){
       let condition = this.state.opened;
       this.setState({opened: !condition });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <Dropdown>
                 <DropdownHandler onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
                     <Avatar title="Roberto"></Avatar>
                 </DropdownHandler>
                 <DropdownContent opened={this.state.opened}>
                     <li>Menu</li>
                     <li>Settings</li>
                 </DropdownContent>
               </Dropdown>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default HeaderConnected;
```

Comment: Yeah! Very fast answer! Thank you. This can be work, I see it. But 
what are the components `Dropdown, DropdownHandler, DropdownContent` used for if these states are not in? Because I would like to use this `Dropdown` component anywhere. not only in `HeaderConnected`

Comment: I think, you should make a reuseble component dropdown, something like your component HeaderConnected  now. And send there content with props.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to do something like that but how send there content with props and keep state in the Dropdown Component ?

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/70848/). This is just a variant :)

Comment: So the idea is to pass DropdownHandler Component AND DropdownContent Component as props of Dropdown Component ? Thats right ?

Comment: Right, but I don't know, is it best solution. I used this structure when I have in component >2 components and I don't know their feature structure. If you sure in your dropdown will be a list of links, for example, you can make something like '<dropDown><Button></Button >{this.state.show? <ul>{this.props.items.map((itemObj) => <li><a href={itemObj.link}>{itemObj.title}</}</a></li>}</ul> : null' and send with props items=[{link:"",title:"},{link:"",title}].

Comment: Yes I understand. But i'm not sure in my Dropdown will be list a links. It can be anything.

Comment: What do you think about the solution I posted? I'm not sure.

Comment: It will work, but i've never done like this, so i don't know how it will work...
Usually, i made a concrete dropdowns components with code i wrote in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to change the name of the callback "onOpen"

```
export class Dropdown extends React.Component {

    state = {
        open: false
    }

    handleOpen = () => {
        this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
    } 

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="DROPDOWN">
                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { open: this.state.open, onOpen: this.handleOpen })}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export class DropdownHandler extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
      open: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      onOpen: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="DROPDOWN__HANDLER" onClick={this.props.onOpen}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export class DropdownContent extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
      open: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      onOpen: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }

    render() {
        // handle visibility here
        return (
            <div className="DROPDOWN__CONTENT">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand this solution :(

Comment: The dropdown component will contains dropdownhandler and dropdowncontent. It give them his open state by props, they can call onOpen props to change the value of open. I supposed your handler component will call this callback (onOpen).

Comment: I understand now. What do you think about the solution I posted? I'm not sure.

Comment: It's surely working, but your component is less scalable. Imagine : while you developpe your app, you realize that your content need state or proper callback... It's less generic, but if you are sure that this components will be the same until the end of the developement, it's work.